# Parsing the django template language code from a variable

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

```
from django import template
from django.template import engines
from django.utils.html import format_html

register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def external_link(link):
    '''
    Creates an anchor tag
    '''
    return format_html('<a target="_blank" href="%s"> Some External Link </a>' % (link))

link = '{% external_link https://stackoverflow.com %}'
template_context = '<div> {{ a_link }} </div>'
template = engines['django'].from_string(template_context)
template.render({
    'a_link': link,
})
```

Current output: `u'<div> {% external_link https://stackoverflow.com %} </div>'`

What I need is: `u'<div> <a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com"> Some External Link </a> </div>'`

How to achieve this by keeping the template code in the variable `link` ?

Comment: What is this tag achieving? why not just put the link directly in?

Comment: The context where I'm using this is logic is different, but I've stripped down the code to the problem I'm facing...

Comment: I'm not really able to try it, but I'd imagine you need `'<div>{}</div>'.format(link)`

Comment: Hi thanks, needed to alter some code according to my context, but the base logic is the same one you have proposed. If you can post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing in a string to be rendered as a context variable, rather than as part of the template you're trying to render.

Simply just include the tag as part of the template string

```
template_context = '<div>{}</div>'.format(link)
```